# Azure issue with Allure

Tags: allure

I got this error while generate and run allure report

throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

````
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'EACCES',
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'spawn /Users/runner/runners/2.160.1/work/_tasks/AllureGenerate_5c975f9d-1c3a-469f-b7c2-8907bf3eacfb/1.0.0/node_modules/allure-commandline/dist/bin/allure',
  path: '/Users/runner/runners/2.160.1/work/_tasks/AllureGenerate_5c975f9d-1c3a-469f-b7c2-8907bf3eacfb/1.0.0/node_modules/allure-commandline/dist/bin/allure',
  spawnargs: [
    'generate',
    '--output',
    '/Users/runner/runners/2.160.1/work/1/s/allure-report/45',
    '/Users/runner/runners/2.160.1/work/1/s/allure-results'
  ]
} ```
````

Comment: Please post the code that caused this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i'm doing this on azure to integrate my code which is using webdriverio with js and when it came to generate  step will give the error

Comment: Is this your problem: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/919

Comment: yes the same issue exactly

Comment: OK. Firstly note the very thorough explanation the person has made on there. Posts on here don't need to be that detailed but need to give us some clue. Your current post doesn't event mention DevOps and really gives us no clue. Secondly you're best off waiting for that bug to be fixed.

Comment: BTW I googled `Allure errno: 'EACCES'` and that's what came up. Most questions here are answerable through google

Comment: There is actually a workaround in that github issue but it's a shame it's necessary

Comment: i mentioned that on azure so it means devops, but this bug since 31 march and no fix yet!! @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: DevOps is one tiny part of Azure. This Allure library is free so there’s no guarantee anyone will ever fix it. It’s open source though so you could try fixing it.